# failure to retrieve MR dicom from dcm4che 2.17.1 mysql

Tags: java, server, dicom, dcm4che

I have a major problem regarding the dcmqr tool, I can successfully retrieve any CT or CR types, but when it comes to MR it fails. I am using windows xp32bit and java 1.8
the terminal message is:

```
C:\dcm4che-2.0.28\bin>dcmqr -L Dev_PC:11114 DCM4CHEE@localhost:11112 -cmove Dev_
PC -cstore MR:PR -cstoredest c:\test_dicom -q00100020=437246
Start Server listening on port 11114
19:01:56,062 INFO   - Start listening on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:11114
19:01:56,125 INFO   - Association(1) initiated Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,p
ort=11112,localport=1827]
19:01:56,125 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1): A-ASSOCIATE-RQ DCM4CHEE << Dev_PC
19:01:56,140 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1): A-ASSOCIATE-AC Dev_PC >> DCM4CHEE
19:01:56,140 INFO   - Connected to DCM4CHEE@localhost:11112 in 0.078 s
19:01:56,218 INFO   - Send Query Request using 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study
 Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND:
(0008,0020) DA #0 [] Study Date
(0008,0030) TM #0 [] Study Time
(0008,0050) SH #0 [] Accession Number
(0008,0052) CS #6 [STUDY] Query/Retrieve Level
(0010,0020) LO #6 [437246] Patient ID
(0020,000D) UI #0 [] Study Instance UID
(0020,0010) SH #0 [] Study ID
(0020,1206) IS #0 [] Number of Study Related Series
(0020,1208) IS #0 [] Number of Study Related Instances

19:01:56,234 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1) << 1:C-FIND-RQ[pcid=1, prior=0
        cuid=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information M
odel - FIND
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian]
19:01:56,265 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1) >> 1:C-FIND-RSP[pcid=1, status=ff00H
        cuid=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information M
odel - FIND
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian]
19:01:56,265 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1) >> 1:C-FIND-RSP[pcid=1, status=0H
        cuid=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information M
odel - FIND]
19:01:56,265 INFO   - Query Response #1:
(0008,0005) CS #10 [ISO_IR 100] Specific Character Set
(0008,0020) DA #8 [20140904] Study Date
(0008,0030) TM #6 [110341] Study Time
(0008,0050) SH #6 [397956] Accession Number
(0008,0052) CS #6 [STUDY] Query/Retrieve Level
(0008,0054) AE #8 [DCM4CHEE] Retrieve AE Title
(0008,0056) CS #6 [ONLINE] Instance Availability
(0010,0020) LO #6 [437246] Patient ID
(0020,000D) UI #36 [1.3.51.0.1.1.10.1.1.71.397956.397930] Study Instance UID
(0020,0010) SH #10 [462884621] Study ID
(0020,1206) IS #2 [12] Number of Study Related Series
(0020,1208) IS #2 [22] Number of Study Related Instances
(0088,0130) SH #0 [] Storage Media File-set ID
(0088,0140) UI #0 [] Storage Media File-set UID

19:01:56,265 INFO   - Received 1 matching entries in 0.125 s
19:01:56,265 INFO   - Send Retrieve Request using 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/St
udy Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - MOVE:
(0008,0052) CS #6 [STUDY] Query/Retrieve Level
(0010,0020) LO #6 [437246] Patient ID
(0020,000D) UI #36 [1.3.51.0.1.1.10.1.1.71.397956.397930] Study Instance UID

19:01:56,281 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1) << 2:C-MOVE-RQ[pcid=7, aet=Dev_PC/?, prior=0
        cuid=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information M
odel - MOVE
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian]
19:01:56,281 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1) >> 2:C-MOVE-RSP[pcid=7, remaining=22, complete
d=0, failed=0, warning=0, status=ff00H
        cuid=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information M
odel - MOVE]
19:01:56,296 INFO   - Association(2) accepted Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=1828,l
ocalport=11114]
19:01:56,296 INFO   - Association(2): A-ASSOCIATE-RQ DCM4CHEE >> Dev_PC
19:01:56,296 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(2): A-ASSOCIATE-AC Dev_PC << DCM4CHEE
19:01:56,296 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(2) >> A-RELEASE-RQ
19:01:56,296 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(2) << A-RELEASE-RP
19:01:56,312 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1) >> 2:C-MOVE-RSP[pcid=7, remaining=null, comple
ted=0, failed=22, warning=0, status=a702H
        cuid=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information M
odel - MOVE
        ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian]
19:01:56,312 INFO   - Retrieved 0 objects (warning: 0, failed: 22) in 0.047s
19:01:56,312 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1) << A-RELEASE-RQ
19:01:56,312 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1) >> A-RELEASE-RP
19:01:56,312 INFO   - Released connection to DCM4CHEE@localhost:11112
19:01:56,312 INFO   - Stop listening on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:11114
19:01:56,312 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(1): close Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=11
112,localport=1827]
19:01:56,359 INFO   - DCM4CHEE(2): close Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=1828,localp
ort=11114]
```

and the server message is:

```
19:01:56,093 INFO  [ServerImpl] handle - Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=1827,localp
ort=11112]
19:01:56,093 INFO  [FsmImpl] Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=1827,localport=11112]
19:01:56,125 INFO  [FsmImpl] received AAssociateRQ
        appCtxName:     1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
        implClass:      1.2.40.0.13.1.1
        implVersion:    dcm4che-2.0
        calledAET:      DCM4CHEE
        callingAET:     Dev_PC
        maxPDULen:      16384
        asyncOpsWindow: maxOpsInvoked=1, maxOpsPerformed=0
        pc-1:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informa
tion Model - FIND
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-3:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.1/Patient Root Query/Retrieve Infor
mation Model - FIND
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-5:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.3.1/Patient/Study Only Query/Retrieve
 Information Model - FIND
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-7:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informa
tion Model - MOVE
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-9:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.2/Patient Root Query/Retrieve Infor
mation Model - MOVE
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-11:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.3.2/Patient/Study Only Query/Retrieve
 Information Model - MOVE
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-13:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4/MR Image Storage
                ts=PR/?
        pc-15:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informa
tion Model - FIND
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-17:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.1/Patient Root Query/Retrieve Infor
mation Model - FIND
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-19:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.3.1/Patient/Study Only Query/Retrieve
 Information Model - FIND
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-21:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informa
tion Model - MOVE
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-23:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.2/Patient Root Query/Retrieve Infor
mation Model - MOVE
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-25:  as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.3.2/Patient/Study Only Query/Retrieve
 Information Model - MOVE
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        RoleSelection[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4/MR Image Storage, scu=false,
 scp=true]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve
 Information Model - FIND, info=00\00\00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.1/Patient Root Query/Retrie
ve Information Model - FIND, info=00\00\00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.3.1/Patient/Study Only Query/
Retrieve Information Model - FIND, info=00\00\00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve
 Information Model - MOVE, info=00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.2/Patient Root Query/Retrie
ve Information Model - MOVE, info=00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.3.2/Patient/Study Only Query/
Retrieve Information Model - MOVE, info=00]
19:01:56,125 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending AAssociateAC
        appCtxName:     1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
        implClass:      1.2.40.0.13.1.1.1
        implVersion:    dcm4che-1.4.31
        calledAET:      DCM4CHEE
        callingAET:     Dev_PC
        maxPDULen:      16352
        asyncOpsWindow: maxOpsInvoked=1, maxOpsPerformed=1
        pc-1:   0 - acceptance
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-3:   0 - acceptance
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-5:   0 - acceptance
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-7:   0 - acceptance
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-9:   0 - acceptance
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-11:  0 - acceptance
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-13:  4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
                ts=PR/?
        pc-15:  4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-17:  4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-19:  4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-21:  4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-23:  4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-25:  4 - transfer-syntaxes-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        RoleSelection[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4/MR Image Storage, scu=false,
 scp=true]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve
 Information Model - FIND, info=00\00\00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.1/Patient Root Query/Retrie
ve Information Model - FIND, info=00\00\00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.3.1/Patient/Study Only Query/
Retrieve Information Model - FIND, info=00\00\00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve
 Information Model - MOVE, info=00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.2/Patient Root Query/Retrie
ve Information Model - MOVE, info=00]
        ExtNegotiation[sop=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.3.2/Patient/Study Only Query/
Retrieve Information Model - MOVE, info=00]
19:01:56,250 INFO  [FsmImpl] received [pc-1] 1:C_FIND_RQ with Dataset
        class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informatio
n Model - FIND
19:01:56,250 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending [pc-1] 1:C_FIND_RSP with Dataset
        class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informatio
n Model - FIND
        status: ff00
19:01:56,250 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending [pc-1] 1:C_FIND_RSP
        class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.1/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informatio
n Model - FIND
        status: 0
19:01:56,281 INFO  [FsmImpl] received [pc-7] 2:C_MOVE_RQ with Dataset
        class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informatio
n Model - MOVE
        move dest:      Dev_PC
19:01:56,281 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending [pc-7] 2:C_MOVE_RSP
        class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informatio
n Model - MOVE
        status: ff00
19:01:56,296 INFO  [FsmImpl] Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=11114,localpor
t=1828]
19:01:56,296 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending AAssociateRQ
        appCtxName:     1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
        implClass:      1.2.40.0.13.1.1.1
        implVersion:    dcm4che-1.4.31
        calledAET:      Dev_PC
        callingAET:     DCM4CHEE
        maxPDULen:      16352
        asyncOpsWindow: maxOpsInvoked=0, maxOpsPerformed=1
        pc-1:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4.1/Enhanced MR Image Storage
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-3:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4.1/Enhanced MR Image Storage
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-5:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.66/Raw Data Storage
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-7:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.66/Raw Data Storage
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
19:01:56,296 INFO  [FsmImpl] received AAssociateAC
        appCtxName:     1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
        implClass:      1.2.40.0.13.1.1
        implVersion:    dcm4che-2.0
        calledAET:      Dev_PC
        callingAET:     DCM4CHEE
        maxPDULen:      16384
        asyncOpsWindow: maxOpsInvoked=0, maxOpsPerformed=1
        pc-1:   3 - abstract-syntax-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-3:   3 - abstract-syntax-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
        pc-5:   3 - abstract-syntax-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-7:   3 - abstract-syntax-not-supported
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
19:01:56,296 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending A-RELEASE-RQ
19:01:56,296 ERROR [QueryRetrieveScpService] No Presentation Context for Storage
 accepted by Dev_PC
java.io.IOException: No Presentation Context for Storage accepted by Dev_PC
        at org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.qrscp.MoveTask.openAssociation(MoveTask.java
:240)
        at org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.qrscp.MoveTask.run(MoveTask.java:354)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
19:01:56,296 INFO  [FsmImpl] received A-RELEASE-RP
19:01:56,296 INFO  [FsmImpl] closing connection - Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.
1,port=11114,localport=1828]
19:01:56,296 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending [pc-7] 2:C_MOVE_RSP with Dataset
        class:  1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2/Study Root Query/Retrieve Informatio
n Model - MOVE
        status: a702
19:01:56,312 INFO  [FsmImpl] received A-RELEASE-RQ
19:01:56,312 INFO  [FsmImpl] sending A-RELEASE-RP
19:01:56,312 INFO  [ServerImpl] finished - Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=1827,loca
lport=11112]
19:01:56,375 INFO  [FsmImpl] closing connection - Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=18
27,localport=11112]
```

What does the status a702 mean? How do i fix the error  [QueryRetrieveScpService] No Presentation Context for Storage
 accepted by Dev_PC?
Please help as soon as possible...

by the way, on the http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-web3 interface, at the search meny, the Modality drop down menu only contains * and CT, where I have loaded a lot of MR dicoms and CR... why didn't it refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it wasn't just that... i fixed it... the dicom i was transfering wasn't just a MRI, it was an enhanced MRI , and it wasn't programmed in the library. I downloaded the dcm4che source files and rebuilded the dcmqr library. There are also a lot more modalities not programmed in... thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your receiving device (Dev_PC) has not been configured to receive MR images with a legal transfer syntax. In your command line

```
dcmqr -L Dev_PC:11114 DCM4CHEE@localhost:11112 -cmove Dev_PC -cstore MR:PR -cstoredest c:\test_dicom -q00100020=437246
```

you are indicating -cstore MR:PR, but 'PR' is not a valid transfer syntax (see http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/d2/dcmqr). You could simply use -cstore or if you really only want to support MR images, -cstore MR:IVRLE.